# how to configure a graph to monitor the memory usage of the servers

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring

I already created the graphics to monitor the CPU usage, Occupancy time, written to disk, but I was not able to configure a graphic for the use of my machines' memory, all are VM mostly Linux and 3 windowns, can anyone give me a suggestion of how do I configure to monitor the percentage of memory usage?

Answer (score 0):

You may install Stackdriver cloud monitoring agent.

Elasticsearch+metricbeat+Kiban will also do.

Comment: Hello, I already have the stackdrive agent installed but I'm trying now and set up a graph to monitor the memory usage of the servers.

Comment: You may refer https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_agent for the setup.

Answer (score 0):

In order to see dashboards for memory usage, you need to [install the Cloud Monitoring agent](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/installation). When you do this you'll have access to [agent metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_agent) one of which is memory.

Just remember to use the 'agent.googleapis.com/agent/' prefix when searching for these metrics in Cloud Monitoring.